# Remove shadow effect on android button

Tags: android, layout, styles, themes

I have added a simple button to my layout , and I have deleted the text and set an image with transparency as its background. but unfortunately there is a drop shadow effect on my button and I can't remove it. I'll appreciate if you have any experience with it help me.
Thanks!

Comment: change to imagebutton and put the background like this: 
            android:background="@android:color/transparent

Comment: Thanks very much , yes that was the problem , could you add it as an answer so I can select it. thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing the shadow on an android button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28744659/removing-the-shadow-on-an-android-button)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your xml , instead of the button that you have, should be like this:

```
    <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/yourimagename"
     android:id="@+id/button1"
     android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
     android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
     android:background="@null"
     />
```

If you have any problems just let me know ;)

Comment: But what if you want a button with text on it?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28756035/how-to-remove-button-shadow-android

Answer (score 78):

on Button tag set

```
android:stateListAnimator="@null"
```

example:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:stateListAnimator="@null"/>
```

Comment: This is a great solution, except it requires API level 21. Is there a solution that will work for lower API levels?

Comment: @Barnaby I guess that the "shadow" effect is added on Lollipop, so lower API levels will not show any shadow by default. Can anyone confirm this?