# Removing the shadow on an android button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button, shadow

I have searched and tryed all found solutions to this.
I need to remove the shadow from a button in android.
Most of the solutions i found involve using an imagebutton and setting it's background. I tryed that and it works but my button has text so imagebutton is not an option. Unless there is a way to write to an imagebutton?

My second solution was:

```
android:fadingEdgeLength="0dp"
```

But nothing seemed to change.
Third:

```
android:shadowColor="@color/application_transparent" />
```

Nothing changed here either.

I also tryed creating a custom shape with stroke 0 and setting the buttons background to it but still nothing.
I prefer to do this in my Xml rather than programmatically but if that is the only way, so be it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: just make your own 9patch image?

Comment: With the text as an image?
I thought of that as a last resort because i am going to translate the app into different languages and that would complicate the translation process by far because i would have to edit each image individually rather than just the strings file.
Is this the only way?

Comment: no just a background image for the button

Comment: Sorry i don't fully understand.
My button background is just simple red color. But il'l give it a shot

Comment: could you share a screenshot?

Comment: I used a TextView, instead of a Button. Now the annoying shadow on the button, with a custom background and state list, is completely gone ! This seems like a Lollipop "feature". I call it another "challenge to get around a nuisance"

Answer (score 71):

How about

```
        <Button
           ..<code>

            android:stateListAnimator="@null"

           ..<code>
       </Button>
```

Comment: Great, welcome to SO :) Please accept as answer so it helps others as well

Comment: I have a problem: "**Attribute "stateListAnimator" is only used in API level 21 and higher**" :(

Comment: That worked! you saved my lots of time. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're most welcome. This small piece of code  seems to be helping a lot of people

Answer (score 3):

Set Style Attribute for Button in xml

```
style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
```

It Works.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, simply adding..

```
android:shadowRadius="0"
```

..in the xml file did the trick.

Comment: Can you confirm you have some style being applied to it, either locally in the xml or even globally?

Comment: I fixed that using Custom Renderer

Answer (score 0):

Alternative for Attribute stateListAnimator used in API level 21 - I wrapped button inside a linear layout, both having same dimensions. Worked for my case.